# ipc_bridge Example Publisher MATLAB Error

Tags: matlab

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've been following the ipc_bridge package ([https://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/~meam620/wiki/index.php?n=Roslab.IpcBridge](https://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/%7Emeam620/wiki/index.php?n=Roslab.IpcBridge)) in order to connect MATLAB to ROS. I've installed MEX Compiler and able to compile every package with the correct version of GCC (with the help of linking mex compiler with the correct gcc version). Note that I'm using Groovy on Ubuntu 12.04.

However, when I try to run the ~/catkin_ws/src/ipc-bridge/ipc_bridge_stack/ipc_bridge_example/example_publisher.m from MATLAB, I get the following errors:

```
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: rospack. 
> In path at 110
  In addpath at 87
  In example_publisher at 9 
Warning: Directory access failure:
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6. 
> In path at 110
  In addpath at 87
  In example_publisher at 9 
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found
(required by /opt/ros/groovy/lib/librospack.so)/bin. 
> In path at 110
  In addpath at 87
  In example_publisher at 9 
Undefined function 'geometry_msgs_Twist' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Error in example_publisher (line 13)
pid=geometry_msgs_Twist('connect','publisher','example_module','twist');
```

What should I do to overcome this? Any help will be greately appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/106506/ipc_bridge-example-publisher-matlab-error/) by [mozcelikors](https://answers.ros.org/users/5390/mozcelikors/) on ROS Answers with karma: 181 on 2013-12-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZYS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25674/zys/) on 2016-01-20**:
Did you solve this problem? I met a problem which is the same as yours.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-21**:
@ZYS: please don't post answers, unless you can actually *answer* a question. Use comments for these kind of things. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to use the ipc_bridge functions, you must first add the path of the specific binary to Matlab:
addpath('Address to the /bin directory of specific message which includes all the mex-compiled binary files')

---

Originally posted by [ZYS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25674/zys/) with karma: 108 on 2016-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0